# Android Layout (Fixed Header + Scrolling section + Fixed Footer)

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am trying to create Android Layout with fixed Header, middle Scrolling section and fixed Footer. 
I've tried everything I've found on StackOverlow and on the net, but nothing seems to work for me. I've so far spent good 5-6 hours now, trying linear and other relative layouts, but it's not working...

Code below is the closest I've got.
It has a working fixed Header and middle scrolling section, but I can't get the fixed footer working...

As soon as I fill a lot of content to **webView2** in the middle scrolling section, footer part actually completely disappears...

Any suggestions or code changes would be more than appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- THIS IS THE TOP FIXED SECTION - TEXTBOX AND BUTTONS BELOW  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/URLtoAdFree"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#CACCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="1dip"
        android:text="Expires Soon"
        android:textColor="#C41B32"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"></TextView>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/devicea"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80px"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="82px"
            android:layout_height="82px"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/setting_icon_82_82"></Button>
    </TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow101"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/speak"
                style="@style/ButtonText"
                android:layout_width="120px"
                android:layout_height="120px"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonup"></Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/shh"
                style="@style/ButtonText"
                android:layout_width="120px"
                android:layout_height="120px"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/shh"
                android:visibility="gone"></Button>
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- THIS IS THE MIDDLE SCROLLING SECTION  -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="#000000"></WebView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/deviceb"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="230dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="12dp"></EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- THIS IS THE BOTTOM FIXED SECTION  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linlay"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/linebreak"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#a9aaaa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#606060"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/peopleaskingtextview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#36A4FF"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="18px"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topstring8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#a9aaaa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#606060"
            android:textSize="25px"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nstextview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:text="© Copyright Note"
            android:textColor="#cccccc"
            android:textSize="10dp"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it possible to make a RelativeLayout, let the header and footer float above the listView?

Comment: I've tried that, it didn't achieve anything better than what I already have. I just need someone with little more skill than I have to look at the code above and see if there is a way to adjust it, so the footer stays fixed. Must be something I am missing there, everything else works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header" 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
android:layout_below="@id/header" android:layout_above="@id/footer">
    ...
    </ScrollView>
```

Goodluck

Comment: I've spent 1 hour adding it to this layout, it's the same issue, footer is getting pushed out when webView2 is filled with content

Comment: The issue is that you have the webview filling up available space in a layout that wraps it's contents (first LinearLayout). I recommend that you have the EditText as part of the footer and have the WebView instead of the ScrollView. This is better as views that scroll inside views that scroll have negative performance and experience effects.

Comment: Using your code I was able to eventually figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using android:layout_weight in your layout. Modify the value of android:layout_weight, until you get the proper layout.
About how to use weight, please check out here,
[1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)
and here,
[2](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)